# How use UITabBar without UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, events, segue, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to use UITabBar with a UITabBarItem, but I need to do this without using a UITabBarController in the storyboard.

I added a `TabBar` and a `TabBarItem` in my `firstViewController`, but I can't trigger or add an event method in my class.

What is the proper way to do this? Could someone outline the next steps to take?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add some code snippet ?

Comment: now I create only Storyboard... I've a MFSideMenu (right) and I need a TabBar too....... I read online this method: - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Messaggi"]) { // or whatever your title is
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueMessaggi" sender:self];
    }
}  but I can't trigger it...

Comment: this code seems right, add 'UITabBarDelegate' protocol to class file and then in class 'viewDidLoad()' make 'self.delegate = self'

Comment: I'm sorry but for me it's fist time to add Protocol.... I read in my .h  @interface myViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate> it's right? and now?? in my .m? can you answer my question?? thank you

Comment: yeah its right way now just call - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item in your .m file

Comment: self.delegate give me an error... "property delegate not found on object of type "myViewController""

Comment: use self.(tabBarInstance).delegate  = self

Comment: thanks!!! if you write me your answer... I give you a point! :)

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and reorganized sentence. Simple question rework for easier understanding by other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To implement particular behaviour on UI element you need to implement respective protocols

---

**Syntax to implement protocols in IOS**

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
```

This way you can implement methods to work with `UITabBar`

---

For further details i would like you to go through official doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html